# How can I send e-mail in C?

Tags: c, email

I'm just wondering how can I send email using C? I Googled it a little bit, but could not find anything proper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sending an email from a C/C++ program in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317305/sending-an-email-from-a-c-c-program-in-linux)

Answer (score 13):

On Unix like systems you can use `system` and `sendmail` as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

        char cmd[100];  // to hold the command.
        char to[] = "sample@example.com"; // email id of the recepient.
        char body[] = "SO rocks";    // email body.
        char tempFile[100];     // name of tempfile.

        strcpy(tempFile,tempnam("/tmp","sendmail")); // generate temp file name.

        FILE *fp = fopen(tempFile,"w"); // open it for writing.
        fprintf(fp,"%s\n",body);        // write body to it.
        fclose(fp);             // close it.

        sprintf(cmd,"sendmail %s < %s",to,tempFile); // prepare command.
        system(cmd);     // execute it.

        return 0;
}
```

I know its ugly and there are several better ways to do it...but it works :)

Comment: Please do not use `system(3)`.

Comment: @ScumCoder, why "Please do not use `system(3)`"?

Comment: @EnriqueRené because it's a gaping security hole. Read the bottom of the man page.

Answer (score 11):

Use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). It supports SMTP and also TLS, in case you need to authenticate for sending.
They offer some [example C code](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html).

Answer (score 6):

A more portable way is to use **libquickmail** (http://sf.net/p/libquickmail), licensed under GPL.
It even allows sending attachments.

Example code:

```
  quickmail_initialize();
  quickmail mailobj = quickmail_create(FROM, "libquickmail test e-mail");
  quickmail_set_body(mailobj, "This is a test e-mail.\nThis mail was sent using libquickmail.");
  quickmail_add_attachment_file(mailobj, "attachment.zip", NULL);
  const char* errmsg;
  if ((errmsg = quickmail_send(mailobj, SMTPSERVER, SMTPPORT, SMTPUSER, SMTPPASS)) != NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "Error sending e-mail: %s\n", errmsg);
  quickmail_destroy(mailobj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `sendmail` and pass the e-mail to its standard input (on unix-like systems), or use some SMTP client library to connect to SMTP mail server.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious choices:

1. Use `system()` to call an existing command-line tool to send mail. Not very portable (requires an external tool with a given calling syntax, etc) but very easy to implement.
2. Use some library.
3. Implement [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) yourself, and talk directly to a mail server. A lot of work.

Comment: Indeed i want to learn how to implement SMTP myself as you mentioned in your third option. Do you know any related tutorial, article or source code?

Comment: In future, try not to recommend system() and instead the exec() family of functions.

Comment: @rogue: Thanks. But system() is more portable, exec*() is Unix only.

Comment: @unwind: it's usually irrelevant, since the command you want to execute is already less portable than the function you use to execute it. E.g, there's not much point insisting on `system("/usr/sbin/sendmail whatever");`, because any system that doesn't have `exec*` isn't going to have `/usr/sbin/sendmail` either. If the command is user-configurable, though, you're in with a chance that system can be made to work.

Comment: I'm referring to the fact that we do not use system() from a program with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges, because strange values for some environment variables might be used to subvert system integrity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mail command also.

Inside the C program using the mail command and system function you can send the mail to the user.

```
 system("mail -s subject  address < filename")

  Example
 system ("mail -s test hello@gmail.com < filename")
```

Note: The file should be exists. If you want to type the content, yiu can type the content inside the file, then send that file to receiver.