# Sending Emails in C

Tags: c, email

I was wondering if there was any way to send an email from C. Perhaps like the email managing functions available in the php library?

Comment: Which platform are you working with? C itself, i.e. standard C, knows nothing about e-mail, but most platforms have some convention for email dispatch.

Comment: I run windows 7 servicepack 1 using cygwin's tools.

Comment: Then you'll have to search for an SMTP library for Windows; it does not have a built-in way to send mail from C (unless you're interfacing with .NET.)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [libESMTP from uklinux.net](http://www.stafford.uklinux.net/libesmtp/) before and it works pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, now are there any tutorials with bits of code for using this?

Comment: Look at the API documentation.

Comment: Excellent though after I install with ./configure, make, and make install, and try the example with make, I get the error  "cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mail-file-a] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkout this answer : [email in c language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363134/14343554)
2. You could execute software that does it for you. Here is an example: [send email form command line](http://www.debianadmin.com/how-to-sendemail-from-the-command-line-using-a-gmail-account-and-others.html)
3. Check out [libquickmail](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail).
   It is especially designed to be small and easy to use in C programs.
   Attachments are also supported.
4. Send Email in Visual C++ : [Tutorial](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vc.aspx?cat=0)

*BTW,This is much easier in Python than c or c++.*