# sending an email from a C/C++ program in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, email, gmail

I would like to send an email to my gmail account everytime my simulation ends. I have tried searching the web and found [sendEmail](http://www.debianadmin.com/how-to-sendemail-from-the-command-line-using-a-gmail-account-and-others.html) but it is timing-out. If anyone could point me out to a package or link that they tried I would be thankful.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use sendmail?http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/sendmail-from-the-command-line-288920/

Comment: I am not the admin of the system so I can't set the system for my gmail account.

Comment: What about opening a socket to an SMTP server and creating a raw email and passing it that way?

Comment: SMTP is a very simple protocol (it's in the name!).

Comment: @Madagascar, If you are not the admin of that computer you can use for example wget , ssh to make a request to your own machine and then use a mail program.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could invoke your local MTA directly using `popen()` and feed it RFC822-compliant text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
int sendmail(const char *to, const char *from, const char *subject, const char *message)
{
    int retval = -1;
    FILE *mailpipe = popen("/usr/lib/sendmail -t", "w");
    if (mailpipe != NULL) {
        fprintf(mailpipe, "To: %s\n", to);
        fprintf(mailpipe, "From: %s\n", from);
        fprintf(mailpipe, "Subject: %s\n\n", subject);
        fwrite(message, 1, strlen(message), mailpipe);
        fwrite(".\n", 1, 2, mailpipe);
        pclose(mailpipe);
        retval = 0;
     }
     else {
         perror("Failed to invoke sendmail");
     }
     return retval;
}

main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc == 5) {
        sendmail(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work well enough as long as you can be sure that `message` doesn't contain `"\n.\n"` as a substring.

Comment: And you must be certain that the final character of `message` is `'\n'`.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, i am new to mail programming, but I would like to use the gmail smtp. How can this be altered to use it?

Comment: @Madagascar isn't that just a case of putting your gmail account in the 'to' field?

Comment: If your local MTA isn't delivering mail how you'd like it to, change it config.

Comment: How would I enter multiple lines in the message?

Comment: @MicroPenguin Include newlines in the string.

Comment: `Hello\n test`
Like this? The message is still one line.

Comment: @trojanfoe It still sends me a message with no newlines.

Comment: @MicroPenguin create a new SO question for your specific problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52325/discussion-between-micropenguin-and-trojanfoe)

Comment: @Robᵩ "_And you must be certain that the final character of message is '\n'_". Using `\n.\n` is not required, `sendmail` will work normally if you just close the pipe after pumping the message body.

Comment: @trojanfoe When my To mail id is having hyphen in it then emails are not sending example "abc-xyz@gmail.com". But I can send mail to any mail other than mails which have hyphen in it. Do I need to add a escape sequence before hyphen in mail or something. Please help me.

Comment: @MasthanValiSyed start another question.

Comment: @trojanfoe here is another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64590144/emails-are-not-sending-when-we-have-hyphen-in-email

Answer (score 5):

[libESMTP](https://github.com/libesmtp/libESMTP) seems to be what you are looking for. It's very well documented and also seems to be under active development (last Release Candidate is from mid-January 2012). It also supports SSL and various authentication protocols.

There are example applications in the source package.

Comment: I'm having a problem with libeSMTP. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146658/this-libesmtp-example-not-showing-any-response)

Comment: the link given in @jupp0r answer is no longer valid but I've found the libESMTP at github repo https://github.com/libesmtp/libESMTP
Looks like it's still under developement

Answer (score 2):

Both [VMime](http://www.vmime.org/) and [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) are good libraries for email sending (and more).

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer of   trojanfoe  above, BUT in my case I needed to turn on an email sending agent.. an MTA to enable linux to send emails -  I have found exim4 to be a relatively simple MTA to get working and that trojanfoe's program works very nicely with it.

to get it to work I used (on a debian type system in a virtual box (crunchbang linux))

> sudo apt-get install exim
>
> sudo apt-get install mailutils

I configured exim4 with

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config

and I told the computer about my normal (remote) email address with

> sudo emacs /etc/email-addresses

hope this might be useful as these were the steps I found worked to get my linux system sending email with trojanfoe's email program above

Comment: Without admin privs this will not be possible.

Comment: @mckenzm this is true - I did this in a virtual machine inside windows, so I had (have) admin priviliges on this machine,

Comment: If (for whatever reason) your *n?x box does not have an MTA, you might as well install Postfix.

Answer (score 1):

Do a fork exec and pipe the body to a program like sendmail/mail:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using std::string;

static const int READEND = 0;
static const int WRITEEND = 1;

int sendEmail(const string& to, const string& subject, const string& body) {
  int p2cFd[2];

  int ret = pipe(p2cFd);
  if (ret) {
    return ret;
  }

  pid_t child_pid = fork();
  if (child_pid < 0) {
    close(p2cFd[READEND]);
    close(p2cFd[WRITEEND]);

    return child_pid;
  }
  else if (!child_pid) {
    dup2(p2cFd[READEND], READEND);
    close(p2cFd[READEND]);
    close(p2cFd[WRITEEND]);

    execlp("mail", "mail", "-s", subject.c_str(), to.c_str(), NULL);

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  close(p2cFd[READEND]);

  ret = write(p2cFd[WRITEEND], body.c_str(), body.size());
  if (ret < 0) {
    return ret;
  }

  close(p2cFd[WRITEEND]);

  if (waitpid(child_pid, &ret, 0) == -1) {
    return ret;
  }

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  return sendEmail("email@hostname.com", "Subject", "Body");
}
```

Comment: Poco is another option https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.MailMessage.html https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SMTPClientSession.html https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SecureSMTPClientSession.html