# Determine if command is successful/exists c

Tags: c, bash, sendmail

How can I determine if a command is successful or exists in C? This will need to be compatible with multiple architectures and routers (don't ask haha)

I was thinking of using popen or system or exec(v)(l). But the command I want to check for is sendmail. Since sendmail is a command that runs forever with no output this will be a little hard to do. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know the path to the command, why not just do a `stat` and see if it is an executable?

Comment: Duplicate of [sending an email from a C/C++ program in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317305/sending-an-email-from-a-c-c-program-in-linux)

Comment: CURL is another good way to send email.

Comment: Calling `sendmail` is fraught with many, many security issues. Beyond that, unless you set the right headers, mail from some random machine is likely to be treated as spam. And `sendmail` isn't always available (you did say routers). I would instead suggest sending mail via an [SMTP server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp). Most mail providers provide one.

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Comment: Holy crap.... why so many downvotes? This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the path to sendmail, then as per the comments, use `stat` to check if it exists and is executable. If you know the search path then iterate through it and check each one.

If not - you could pass it `/dev/null` as stdin, in which case it will print an error message and exit. Then you can inspect the exit code from the process - for POSIX systems, the exit code will be 127 if the command could not be executed:

```
int rc = system("sendmail </dev/null 2>/dev/null");
if (WEXITSTATUS(rc)!=127) {
    /* sendmail was found */
}
```

Of course this requires `/dev/null` to exist and shell redirects to be available.

I redirected stderr also, otherwise you will get error messages output from sendmail.

Comment: The `system` function won't return if `sendmail` don't exit or terminate.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it will terminate if you feed it from /dev/null. When you start it as shown above it tries to read from stdin

Comment: Thankyou. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use it. If it's there, and you can execute it, it'll work. If it isn't, it won't and you can see why in `errno`.

The reason you don't try to check beforehand is twofold, and it's the same with files as with executables. First, you might get the check wrong. A lot of people will make the mistake of checking if a file *exists* and then wonder why opening it fails. They forgot to check if it's readable. There's no need to duplicate all these checks, just try to open it and see.

The second is it invites a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). For example, let's say you have two processes working on the same file. Time is moving down.

```
Process 1                              Process 2
Check if file is readable.
It's readable!
                                       Make the file unreadable.
Open that file.
File fails to open.
```

That's a very simple example, there are far, far worse consequences to a race condition. It illustrates that checking if a resource can be used and using that resource must be [*atomic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability): it has to happen in one single uninterruptible operation.

---

Avoid `popen` and `system` where you can. They run the command through the shell which invites security holes and unintended consequences of non-alphanumeric characters. Instead, use one of the `exec[lv]p` functions that will search the `PATH` for the executable without invoking a shell.